# proper way to import modules in python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've a project like:

```
./project_dir/
├── project.py
├── __init__.py
└── lib
    ├── constants.py
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── a.py
    ├── b.py
    ├── test_a.py
    └── test_b.py
```

in `a.py`

if i do
`import constants`

and in `b.py` i do
`from a import someClass`

what would be the proper way to import **a** and **b** in `project.py` ?
It usually throws

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'a'
```

how to import things from a and b?

Comment: `from lib import a,b`

Comment: I believe circular dependencies end up raising the same error. If the solution in comment above does not solve your problem, you probably have a circular dependency cycle. (Pro tip: you can put print statements at the module level to observe the order of module loading. Circular dependencies usually arise from some weirdness in the init file, but that is my experience.)

Comment: Thanks @PedroRodrigues i suspected circular dependency. ill try it out.

Comment: Great. Elaborating a bit on my previous comment. A common pitfall is importing a module that imports another module. The first module may have imported partially and may not be totally available to the module its trying to import. In other words, if A imports B and C, at the time of importing B module A may not have the attributes it requires C for, if B attempts to use them during import.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

complete solution:

project.py

```
from lib import a,b
```

a.py

```
from . import constants

class someClass:
    pass
```

b.py

```
from .a import someClass
```

Answer (score 1):

Module not found lets you know that it hasn't been discovered in the current path. If you're active in the project.py directory (which is normal when running from there), you'll need to include as follows:

```
from lib.a import someClass

# call someClass
var = someClass()
```

or

```
from lib import a,b

# call someClass
var = a.someClass()
```

Comment: from lib import a,b